# Affordable way to test frequency range of a 2.4GHz device

Tags: rf, bluetooth, frequency-measurement, spectrum-analyzer

Does anyone know of a good/affordable way to test the frequency range of a RF device (e.g., Bluetooth module)? Not spectrum analysers since they're rather unaffordable. Are there relatively affordable tools for measuring the range? I heard about SDR, but AFAIK they don't do 2.4Ghz. How about RTL-SDR with [downconverter](http://www.rtl-sdr.com/tag/downconverter/), perhaps with something like [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/2014-Best-selling-MMDS-Downconverter-with-L-o-frequency-1998MHz-from-China-lnb-factory/402505_1910382011.html)? Is it accurate?

How about HackRF?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Spectrum analyzers are the tools of the trade. If you cannot afford one, lease one. If you cannot afford a new one, get a used one.
Also, There are several spectrum analyzers at the sub 1K USD range, mainly USB based devices such as the Signalhound SA44.

Answer (score 1):

[Wi-Spy](http://www.metageek.com/products/wi-spy/) is a USB spectrum analyser for 2.4 GHz. It is designed for tracking down interference with WiFi networks so it won't be as frequency accurate as a more expensive and bigger analyser.